# How to add an automatic creation date in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Before version 2.0, you would create a field `_timestamp` in your type:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html

Unfortunately, this has been deprecated. The new replacement for this is the 'date' field but this has to be filled explicitly.

Is there a way to auto generate a creation date?

Comment: If you use Logstash to index your documents, you could delegate this task to Logstash.

Comment: Such a pitty, I though that someone might know some trick by using a scripted filed or something alike.

Answer (score 6):

According to [the breaking changes documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal_deprecated) `_timestamp` is deprecated and there is no dedicated replacement for it:

> Instead of the _timestamp field, use a normal date field and set the value explicitly.

That means that it is entirely up to the client to set the documents creation time.